# New line space is lost with reading & setting the content

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read a file, put some content & save the same file using PowerShell. Below is my script:

```psh
$x=file.txt
$old='Hi'
$new='Hello'
(Get-Content $x | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "$old","$new"}) | Set-Content $x
```

File content:

```
Hi

World!!!
```

After running the script, new line space is getting lost. Now file looks as below:

Content after script execution:

```
Hello
World!!!
```

I don't want new line space to be lost & format should be same. I am expecting output as below:

```
Hello

World!!!
```

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly create the output you claim it does. Aside from the fact that the first line would throw an error, the loop would write the filename to each line of the output file. Please do not lie about your code if you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: Just in case you're wondering, your code is still broken and will throw an error in the first line. Other than that it does what you expect it to do. For further help with your problem **POST YOUR ACTUAL CODE**, not something you fabricated or typed from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using carriage return + new line `` `r`n ``, maybe like this:

```
$new='Hello `r`n'
```

Comment: That might work as a workaround, but it's not a real solution to the underlying problem. Also, escape sequences are not expanded in single quoted strings.